# Publish ASP.NET Website does not work with MS Build but works with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am having a bit of trouble with attempting to File Deploy a series of ASP.NET Websites from a single solution using MSBuild. I have created publish profiles for each website and have named the profiles the same as I can only provide a single profile name to MS build.

If I choose Publish on a single site using Visual Studio 2013 I get the build output I expect and in the location I expect. However, if I use MSBuild on the solution file using the following command (which may be incorrect) I do not get any files published to the locations I expect.

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Debug
```

note: I am using the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 to get access to MSBuild.

any direction is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618467/tfs-msbuild-args-pdeployonbuild-true-doesnt-seem-to-do-anything