# Continuous deployment Team foundation server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment, build-server

I am currently researching ways in which I can automatically deploy an application upon a successful merge from Main to a Virtual Machine.

i.e. when merging from dev to main tfs builds our application and deploys it to our test VM.

I was hoping someone would point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: This is too broad for SO. Are you having trouble installing TFS, building from TFS, deploying a build, building upon check-in, [setting up a build branch](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/160239/does-continuous-integration-involve-automatic-merging-between-branches)? Please show some research effort and ask a specific question.

Comment: I have TFS setup and configured. With automated nightly builds and unit testing. I have a windows service that I want to install and start upon a successful build. All i wanted was a pointer in the direction of how to achieve this?

Comment: Use continuous integration build option to trigger your build (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh395023(v=vs.110).aspx#CreateBuild)  when you merge the code and use this link http://mrchief.calepin.co/deploying-windows-service-via-msbuild/ so that you can deploy your service using msbuild option.

Comment: Try this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618467/tfs-msbuild-args-pdeployonbuild-true-doesnt-seem-to-do-anything/18619378#18619378

Comment: Look at Release Management for TFS. It does exactly what you want. Don't overextend the build process.